# simple add_rewrite_rule added, refuses to work

Tags: url-rewriting

Bottom of my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'init', 'new_rules');
function new_rules(){
add_rewrite_rule('(.+?)/status/?$','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]-train-status',"top");
}
```

Totally works in monkeyman's rewrite analyzer http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/

But fails in practice - I get a 404 Not Found. Shows up in $wp_rewrite->rules when i print it.

```
/?pagename=a-train-status
```

works fine

```
/a/status
```

fails